# How to put single quotes around variables in a dynamic query

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to build a dynamic query. Initially @Query is set to the query string and then I want to dynamically add the WHERE clause. It works, except it isn't putting the single quotes around the strings in this case @val. This causes an error. How do I include the single quotes so that it adds them correctly?

This is what I've tried:

```
SET @Query = @Query + ' WHERE ' + '' + @param + ' ' + @operator + ' ' + '' + @val + '' ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing (because I don't know for sure) is because you're adding `''` which is empty. If one single quote denotes the start of the string, and one denotes the end, there's nothing in the middle. If you want one in the middle you might need to have `'''`.

Comment: use backslashes to escape: `... + '\'' + ...`, but this leaves you open to sql injection vulnerabilities, so you'd be better off preparing a statement with placeholders.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? MySQL doesn't use `+` to do string concatenation, it uses the `CONCAT()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to place a quote in between the quotes, but escape it so it doesn't break your code. It would look like the following:

```
SET @Query = @Query + ' WHERE ' + '' + @param + ' ' + @operator + ' ' + '\'' + @val + '\'' ;
```

**Edit:** Eric Anderson's answer works as well. Take from the [MySQL 5.0 Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

> A “'” inside a string quoted with “'” may be written as “''”.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
SET @Query = @Query + ' WHERE ' + '' + @param + ' ' + @operator + ' ' + '''' + @val + '''' ;
```

Programming can be very stupid sometimes. Good ol' 4 single quotes.

Thanks anyways guys.

Comment: Why do you have `+ '' +` after `WHERE`? What's the purpose of concatenating an empty string there?

Comment: because otherwise it will look like "WHERE param=val"
I just wanted it to look like "WHERE param = val"

Comment: I'm not talking about the quotes around `val`, I'm talking about the quotes before `@param`.

Comment: What a nice cabbage full of interesting exploits you got there. Also Barmar asked a valid question. I just hope that others, who stumble upon this question won't do what you did, this is horrible.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that my first day using MySQL isn't wowing you. Perhaps if you provided constructive criticism instead of being deliberately negative then people would learn from their mistakes.

Comment: @Barmar those should not be there, that was my attempt to ad single quotes to a variable and then I realized that was in the wrong spot anyway, forgot to take them out.

Comment: @EricAnderson - but there are great suggestions posted by other people here. For example, one suggestion was to create a prepared statement (directly from MySQL). That alone will help you not to produce possible injections, and it'll reduce the amount of concatenation you're doing, among other things. But, as many people - instead of asking *how* to do it or *why* - you opted for your own brute force solution. So it's not really relevant if you're new to MySQL as much how susceptible to suggestions you might be. Am I wrong?

Comment: Eric: Please take @N.B.'s comment as targeted at your *post*, not *you*. Considering that, I think it's important to take into account the information about SQL Injection exploits that your code is vulnerable to. *Now* is the time to learn to use parametered queries, and not string concatenation - before you get into bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DECLARE @SQ [varchar](1) = ''''

SET @Query = @Query + ' WHERE ' + @SQ + @param + @SQ + ' ' + @operator + ' ' + @SQ + @val + @SQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN

set @mulai=_tanggalmulai;
set @akhir=_tanggalakhir;

IF @mulai <> '' && @akhir <> '' THEN
SET @setWhere=' and date(created_at) between STR_TO_DATE(@mulai,''%d/%m/%Y'') and STR_TO_DATE(@akhir,''%d/%m/%Y'')';
ELSEIF @mulai <> '' && @akhir = '' THEN
SET @setWhere=' and date(created_at) > NOW()';
ELSEIF @mulai = '' && @akhir <> '' THEN
SET @setWhere=' and date(created_at) < NOW()';
ELSE
SET @setWhere=' ';
END IF;

SET @qry=CONCAT('SELECT id,norekammedik,nama,jeniskelamin,tempatlahir,nohp,alamat,DATE_FORMAT(tanggallahir,''%d/%m/%Y'') as tanggallahir,DATE_FORMAT(created_at,''%d/%m/%Y'') as created_at FROM pasien where 1=1',@setWhere,' ORDER BY id DESC');

PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, you will need to know that `+` isn't the string-concatenation operator (that's non-standard syntax in Microsoft SQL Server and Access).

MySQL uses a builtin function [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
SET @Query = CONCAT(@Query, ' WHERE ', @param, @operator, '?');
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @val;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

Or you can set [ANSI](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) mode (or more specifically [PIPES_AS_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat) mode) and use SQL-standard string concatenation:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ANSI';
SET @Query = @Query || ' WHERE ' || @param || @operator || '?';
PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
EXECUTE stmt USING @val;
DEALLOCATE stmt;
```

For values, you don't need the `?` placeholder in quotes in the SQL expression, in fact it must not be in quotes, or else it'll be a literal `'?'` string, not a parameter placeholder.

You can't parameterize column names or operators, only values.